# Combine django and react

Tags: reactjs, django, apk, web-development-server, django-react

I am doing this using axios to combine django and react.
While running the program in the command prompt I have to use 2 command prompt!
One for running (npm start)
And the another for backend (python manage.py runserver)

My questions:
Is there a way to run a single command in a single command prompt then both the commands should managed. How industries merge them both

Can we use the same program and change as an apk file and use in mobile app?

Comment: you can use react as CDN in your template check this official doc . https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html and check this post for how use django using react https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/reactify-django

Answer (score 0):

Django and React(webpack or whatever you are using) are 2 different processes and should be run in 2 different terminals.

As for running React as a mobile app, I recommend react-native, which is basically the same framework but with native (Android and iOS)APIs added.